# Reuse of Angularjs services and factories by Nodejs scripts

Tags: angularjs, node.js

My web app calculate price for quotes on the client-side. It makes use of Angular services and factories to achieve that.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp");

myApp.service("quoteCalculator", function () {
    var calculator = {
        getPrice: function (quoteData) {
            return 402.56;            
        }
    }
    return calculator;
});
```

Now there is a requirement which I'll need to calculate prices on the server-side. Since this logic is in JavaScript and lives inside an Angular service, I didn't want to repeat the calculation logic in C# code on the server-side for obvious reasons.

Question: Using Nodejs, is there a way where I could reuse my angular service "quoteCalculator" calling from a Node.js script?

Comment: How would you be calling this node.js script from C# code? And would you be able to make changes to your angular code to assist Node in being able to use it? Like putting a simple `if (module) module.exports = myApp` at the end, and/or possibly a `if(!angular && require) angular=require('angular')` as sort of a dependency injection of a custom "angular" module for use in Node?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with the code like below.

```
(function(is_node, is_angular) {

function quoteCalculator(){
    this.getPrice = function(){
        return 402.56;
    };
}

if (is_angular) {
    angular.module('my-service', [])
        .service('quoteCalculator', quoteCalculator);
} else if (is_node) {
    module.exports.quoteCalculator = quoteCalculator;
}

})(typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports,
   typeof angular !== 'undefined'
   );
```

I always use this structure when I want to share some logic between client and server. I hope it could help you. :)